# How to dispaly a layout above another without to hide it but only Blackout of it?

Tags: android, layout, dictionary

i want to dispaly a layout above another without to hide it but only Blackout of it

thanks...

Comment: If you want a response you need to be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 states you can use:

- setVisibility(View.GONE) - will remove the element completely
- setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) - will retain the space, but make it
  invisible

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `FrameLayout`. All children that you put in a `FrameLayout` will be placed on top of each other.